# Why does SVM needs to keep support vectors?

Tags: classification, svm

I am reading the book Artificial Intelligence a Modern Approach and I have trouble understanding why the SVM needs to keep support vectors.

From the book:

> SVMs are a nonparametric method -- they retain training examples an
>   potentially need to store them all. On the other hand, in practice
>   **they often end up retaining only a small fraction of the number of
>   examples**.

And then:

> A final important property is that the weights associated with each data point are zero except for the support vectors -- the points closest to the separator. Because there are usually many fewer support vectors than examples SVMs gain some of the advantages of parametric models.

Source: Artificial Intelligence a Modern Approach  p746

As the SVMs separator is defined by a hyperplane w.x + b = 0 we only need to know w and b to make predictions. Why should it keep all the support vectors?

Comment: I think what it is trying to say is the optimal $w$ is dependent on just the small number of support vectors. You are correct that once $w$ is computed you don't really need to save these support vectors if you just need to classify. However if new data points arrive in the future, you may have to store all of them and recompute $w$ every time with new data.

Comment: "they often end up retaining only a small fraction of the number of examples." your mileage may vary on this one, in my experience if you choose the hyper-parameters to maximise generalisation performance you quite often end up with virtually all the data being support vectors.  This depends on the nature of the problem and the hyper-parameter settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that the SVM decision function $w \cdot x + b$ depends only on $w$ and $b$, however it can be shown that $w$ can be expressed as *a sum of support vectors*. You can consult [Stanford's](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf) or [MIT's](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-097-prediction-machine-learning-and-statistics-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT15_097S12_lec12.pdf) course notes, pages 12 and 5 respectively, but basically it can be shown with optimization theory that the optimal weight vector $w^*$ can be written in the following form:

$$
w^*=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\alpha_i^*y_ix_i}
$$

where $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_i$ is your data $-$ $x_i$ are the attributes, $y_i$ the labels and $a_i$ Lagrangian coefficients. Further, it can be shown that only a fraction of the $\alpha_i$'s are non zero; vectors $(x_i,y_i)$ for which $\alpha_i>0$ are called *support vectors*, so that is why you need to store all of them and only them to make further predictions $-$ check page 13 of Stanford's course; check also page 7 of MIT's course. So if $N_{sv}$ is the number of support vectors, $\{(x_i^{sv},y_i^{sv})\}_i$ the support vectors and $\alpha_i^{sv}$ their corresponding alphas $-$ which are all strictly positive $-$ we can write the optimal $w^*$ as follows:

$$
w^*=\sum_{i=1}^{N_{sv}}{\alpha_i^{\,sv\,*}y_i^{\,sv}x_i^{\,sv}}
$$

The optimal decision function is then:

$$
f_{SVM}^*(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_{sv}}{\alpha_i^{\,sv\,*}y_i^{\,sv}(x_i^{\,sv}\cdot x)}+b^*
$$

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me this question is more about "*why do we keep the support vectors (because after all what we want is the decision boundary)*" than "*what are support vectors for*".

AFAIK it's because SVMs are often used together with kernels. Without kernels, it is sufficient to store only the decision boundary $wx+b=0$, and throw away the support vectors.

Kernels can be thought of as mapping the input to an implicit feature space, of which the dimensionality can be infinite (e.g. for RBF kernels). So using the decision boundary explicitly in such high dimensional space would be inefficient (or impossible).

If we decompose the decision boundary as a function of some support vectors (as shown in Daneel Olivaw's answer) then the computation would depend only on the number of support vectors and the kernel function.

---

If fact if we don't use kernels, NOT to keep support vectors is more efficient in both time and space.

Say the dimension of the data is $m$ and the number of support vectors is $k$, we need $O(km)$ space to store $k$ vectors, and the time complexity for inference is also $O(km)$ because we need the inner product between the input vector and all the support vectors. Well if we only keep the parameters, the time and space complexity is both $O(m)$.